# How to catch scrapy exception which occur while saving item in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am running a spider in scrapy after every 24 hours. The item scraped from spider is stored in MySQL database. To collect only unique item, I set up table structure to void duplicate records. Therefore the Duplicate entry error occurred in most of cases. I need to capture all those & prevent them to be get printed on console/terminal. Below is the snapshot for the error.

```
2020-08-27 07:02:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'jobtitle': ['E-Learning Specialist'],
 'joburl': ['https://******/e-learning-specialist-1530588']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/scrapym0/scrapy/BotV0.1/test2/test2/pipelines.py", line 85, in process_item
    self.store_db(item)
  File "/home/scrapym0/scrapy/BotV0.1/test2/test2/pipelines.py", line 100, in store_db
    self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO JobList(Job_Title,Job_URL,entry_date) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'https://******/e-learning-specialist-1530588' for key 'JobList.Job_URL_UNIQUE'
```

Comment: there are 2 ways to do this, you can overwrite existing field (if duplicate) or simply put line 100 in a try/except

Comment: Try/except may work. Can you help me how to catch only error code 1062 or 23000 which raised for duplicate entry. I want other errors get published on terminal / console.

Comment: How about using `INSERT IGNORE table`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I hope this will work for single row insert statement also. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try/except block is working as expected

```
try:
  self.curr.execute("SQL_statement")
except mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError:
  pass
```